# What's the difference between CollabNet SVN and TortoiseSVN's svnserve as a server?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, collabnet

We currently have a Win 2008 R2 Server setup with Tortoise SVNSERVE.EXE running as a service.  We are forbidden to run a webserver.  A couple of projects want to add repositories to our server and suggested we "upgrade" to CollabNet Subversion.  What would we gain by doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source for Subversion (which is from Apache) is free and open. TortoiseSVN and CollabNet uses the same set of source files to build their command line tools.

The main difference will be one of support. The TortoiseSVN project provides a complete set of command line tools, but really doesn't support them. In fact, if you look at [TortoiseSVN's on line documentation on `svnserve`](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-serversetup-svnserve.html), you see they tell you to use CollabNet's version of `svnserve`.

There's also the question of how the code is compiled and tested. CollabNet probably does a lot more thorough testing of their version of svnserve to make sure it will work under a wide variety of circumstances. Considering the cost of *upgrading* to CollabNet is free, You should opt for the CollabNet package for running your Subversion server.

TortoiseSVN's version of `svnserve` is probably fine if you're using Subversion for your own personal use, but when you're taking about a corporate team, you should really opt for one of the many Subversion distributions that is specifically made for server use.

Comment: OK, thank you both!  I knew both were command-line based, and I'm relatively new to SVN, so I was not sure there was any appreciable difference between the two svnserve executables.

Answer (score 9):

*FULL DISCLOSURE:  I am a veteran Subversion developer and a CollabNet employee.*

It's difficult to imagine what immediate *technical* benefit you'd get from running CollabNet's packaged 'svnserve' utility versus the one that ships with TortoiseSVN.  The primary difference will be the additional support offered by CollabNet for the version they provide.

I can't help but wonder, though, if the folks urging you to install "CollabNet Subversion" are, in fact, urging you to consider CollabNet's Subversion Edge product.  (At the risk of sounding like an advertisement) Subversion Edge offers a free, open-source, web-administered Subversion server in a single easy-to-install package.  As Subversion server packages go, it's a good one, but it's specifically because Subversion Edge provides a clean interface for such actions as "Create a new repository" that I'm supposing your users mean Edge when they say merely "CollabNet Subversion".  Unfortunately, it is Apache-based (and distinctly *not* svnserve-based), so I don't think it would pass your strict "no web servers allowed" policy.

I suggest you get your users to qualify what, precisely, they want, since neither of the options they *seem* to be suggesting offers additional technical value which is overwhelmingly obvious but also fits within your deployment limitations.  (Alternatively, see about getting that "no web servers" ban lifted and give Subversion Edge a spin for yourself.)

Comment: I agree with this. This _no web server_ idea seems pretty lame. With Subversion using Apache httpd, you can use LDAP or Windows Active Directory for authentication including LDAP/AD groups. It makes administering Subversion a whole lot easier. CollabNet's Subversion Edge is a new package that includes Apache httpd, and a properly configured Subversion for Apache. There are other packages which are a bit easier to use because they have a GUI frontend. However, if you're technical, setting up Subversion Edge isn't difficult.

Comment: I would love to have the Subversion Edge, or even https Apache. I know it would be infinitely more useable, but unfortunately, this is a highly regulated environment.  There is no chance of removing this restriction.

Comment: I appreciate the full disclosure addition before this.